# Joda-Time DateTime.minusDays() Error in jdbc query

Tags: java, jodatime, jdbctemplate

I am facing strange problem while running jdbc query and passing joda date time in the param.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime lookbackDays = now.minusDays(60);
```

Column definition:

```
  @CreatedDate
    @NotNull
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @ColumnDefault("now()")
    protected DateTime createdDate = DateTime.now();
```

While passing `now` as a param(passing inside a map, and naming are ok matching with the query for both cases), my jdbc query works fine, but for `lookbackDays`, it gives exception like below:

> nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of org.joda.time.DateTime. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.

Comment: You shouldn't use Joda-Time here, use the java.time classes.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not using the `java.time` package, but instead JodaTime?

Comment: Joda time has effectively been rendered obsolete by `java.time` so relying on its continued support is a bad plan

Comment: @MCEmperor I have no option but to use this

Comment: Hard to tell based on what you've presented.  Does it work if you specify `minusDays(0)` to not change the date?  Could it be a lack of a map value based on a different `DateTime`?  Just guesses here.

Comment: @WJS, haven't tried with `minusDay(0)`. In the map, I am just setting the same variable, nothing else

Comment: @WJS, it works. It works if I set subtract 2 months, instead of 60 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after changing this way:

```
DateTime lookbackDays = now.minusMonths(2);
```

Comment: *My assumption is, they don't allow more than 31 days to subtract in terms of days.*  Who is `they`? Subtracting 60 days returned a valid DateTime instance.  What if you manually set the date to 60 days earlier by parsing?  Something else may be going on  here.

Comment: `they` -> I meant joda date time lib.  However, subtracting 60 days gives a valid date time  no doubt about that.